# Different data type volatile unsigned int to const char ,

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, c, firmware

I have to reply via SMS the value of a variable if the password is sent to arduino by help of sim900. I am able to switch an led on successfully. Now I want the arduino to reply to me the variable value but I am getting typecasting problem.

Here is the code I am using:

```
#include "SIM900.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "sms.h"

SMSGSM sms;
//Number of pulses, used to measure energy.
volatile unsigned int pulseCount1_Wh  = 0;   
volatile unsigned int pulseCount1_kWh = 0;  
char number[]="8763983139";
char message[180];
char message1[180]; 
char pos;
char *p;
const int ledPin =  13;   

void onPulse1()
{
    //pulseCounter
    pulseCount1_Wh++;
    if(pulseCount1_Wh == 6400)
    {
        pulseCount1_Wh = 0;
        pulseCount1_kWh++;
    }
}

void setup()
{
  // KWH interrupt attached to IRQ 0  = pin2
 attachInterrupt(0, onPulse1, RISING);
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); 
 if (gsm.begin(9600))
 Serial.println("\nstatus=READY");
 else Serial.println("\nstatus=IDLE");
};

void loop()
{
 pos=sms.IsSMSPresent(SMS_UNREAD);
 Serial.println((int)pos);
 if((int)pos>0&&(int)pos<=20){
   Serial.print("NUOVO MESSAGGIO, POS=");
   Serial.println((int)pos);
   message[0]='\0';
   sms.GetSMS((int)pos,number,message,180);
   p=strstr(message,"testpwd");
   if(p){       
     Serial.println("PSWD OK");
     digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);
     p=strstr(message,"LEDON");
     strcat(message1, pulseCount1_Wh);
     strcat(message1,"PIN");
     sms.SendSMS(number,message1);
     delay(100);
     if(p){
       Serial.println("LED ON");
     }
     else{
       p=strstr(message,"LEDOFF");
       if(p){
         Serial.println("LED OFF");
         digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
         delay(100);
       }
     }
   }
   sms.DeleteSMS((int)pos);
 }
 delay(5000);
};
```

Comment: Will you be sharing the error messages with us as well?

Answer (score 2):

From your code, you've defined "pulseCount1_Wh" as "volatile unsigned int" type.

> volatile unsigned int pulseCount1_Wh  = 0;

But you directly pass it to "strcat" which expect to receive a pointer as the second argument.

> strcat(message1, pulseCount1_Wh);

I think you just want to show the count number as a string. So, your problem is not "just" a typecast problem. You should use "sprintf" or other data format functions to format the integer "pulseCount1_Wh"  into a string buffer, then pass the pointer of the string buffer to "strcat".